# Lightning Custom Email Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template

Is there any way to pull other records (not the main record) into a custom email component? the documentation seems pretty ironclad on this with no fetch and no wire but just wondering if anyone has a workaround.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_email_builder_custom_components_tips

Comment: I had similar questions about custom email builder components. Submitted a feature request to the lwc-recipes project for examples. They've agreed to work on it, but still waiting: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/654

Comment: I'll watch with baited breath then.